# keep the record of the number of clicks on an external link or internal link on the page

Tags: php, jquery

I try to implement the following code:

```
  <a href = "http://www.google.com"/ id="external">go to google</a>
   <span  id="num1"></span>// to show the number of clicks so far.
  <a href = "index.php" id="internal">go to home</a>
  <span id="num2"></span>>// to show the number of clicks so far.


<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var count1=0;
    var count2=0;
    $("#external").click(function(){
        count1++;

   });
 $("#num1").html(count1);
    $("#internal").click(function(){
        count2++
   });
  $("#num2").html(count2);

  });

</script>
```

I am not sure what I did above is right for the purpose of keeping track of the number of clicks on each link, and the problem is that when the page is loaded again, the count variable will be reset to 0, I wonder if I need to insert the count variable into database or is there even more efficient way to do this, any one could help me with that, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: has to be stored somewhere, currently your storing the count on the users browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hi-jack the `click` event for the links, stopping the normal flow, sending an AJAX request to your sever to log the click, and then redirect the user to the requested URL:

```
$('#external, #internal').on('click', function (event) {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    event.preventDefault();
    $.get('path/to/server-side.php', { 'vote' : url }, function (serverResponse) {
        window.location = url;
    });
});
```

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and in this case is the same as using `.bind()`.

You can also select all links:

```
$('a')...
```

Or you can add a class to links you want to log

```
$('.log-this-link')...
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript will be "reset" every time a page is loaded. In order to keep track of the clicks you'll have to store the data in a database.

Comment: can you show me how in php? thanks! I assume using "mysql_query("insert into count1 values('count1'), but that the javascript varible count1 can not be in database query.